# UFT/VB code to compare two xml's ignoring child element ordering

Tags: xml, vbscript, hp-uft

I want to compare two xml's ignoring child order
eg:

File1.xml
    
    a
    12

File2.xml
    
    12
    a

It has to ignore the order and compare the files.

I tried with code,but it does not ignore the ordering
    Set doc = XMLUtil.CreateXML()

```
On error resume next
doc.LoadFile strF1
intErr1 = err.number

Set doc1 = xmlutil.CreateXML()
doc1.Load doc.ToString      
err.clear

Set docX = XMLUtil.CreateXML()
On error resume next
docX.LoadFile strF2
intErr2 = err.number
Set doc2 = xmlutil.CreateXML()
doc2.Load docX.ToString

res = doc1.Compare(doc2,resultDoc)
print res
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is actually rather complicated to implement yourself. To run a comparison but be tolerant of differences gets messy very quickly.
You would really want a third party library to accomplish that.

However if the files are expected to be perfectly identical except for the order of elements, then I suggest doing a line sort of the files alphabetically and comparing that way.  Since that's all you specified in your question then it should be fine.

To do that you can split the string of xml by line break into an array of lines and do a bubble sort:

```
for a = UBound(linearray) - 1 To 0 Step -1
    for j= 0 to a
        if linearray(j)>linearray(j+1) then
            temp=linearray(j+1)
            linearray(j+1)=linearray(j)
            linearray(j)=temp
        end if
    next
next
```

Repeat that for each string of data and your strings should match.